# Passport: Unknown authentication strategy "local"

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm new to NodeJS and I try to build a login/registration system. Registration works fine but I'm currently unable to login.

I find a example app using passport and nodejs, so based on this example I build the registration form and the login form. 
http://blog.robertonodi.me/node-authentication-series-email-and-password/

When I try to login I get an `'Unknown authentication strategy "local" error'`. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

## My code

(edit: added some changes from answers/comments and filenames)

### Express config (config/express.config.js)

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: 'mongodb://' + config.url + ':' + config.port + '/' + config.name
    }),
    secret: 'secretkey',
    key: 'skey.sid',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie : {
        maxAge: 604800000 //7 days in miliseconds
    }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require(path.join(__dirname, 'auth.config'))(passport); //Load passport config

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.resources = req.resources || {};
   // res.locals.app = config.app;
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals._t = function (value) { return value; };
    res.locals._s = function (obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj); };
    next();
})
```

### Passport config (config/auth.config.js)

```
var path = require('path');

var passport=require('passport');
var User = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'models', 'user.model'));

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        done(null, false);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        console.log("deserializeUser called", id);
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    //load strategy files
    require(path.join(__dirname, 'strategies', 'local-strategy'));
    //TODO: Facebook
    //TODO: Twitter
    //TODO: Google
}
```

### Local strategy (/config/strategies/local-strategy.js)

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports = function () {
    console.log("LocalStrategy called");
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password'
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.authenticate(username, password, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if(!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
            }

            return done(null, user);
        })
    }))
}
```

### Auth Controller (login only) (/controllers/auth.controller.js)

```
module.exports.loginUser = function(req,res, next) {
    console.log("Auth.config", path.join(__dirname, 'strategies', 'local-strategy'))
   passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
       if (err || !user) {
           console.log("Error", info);
           return res.status(400).send(info);
       }

       req.logIn(user, function(err) {
           if (err) {
              return next(err);
              // return res.status(404).send("Username or password incorrect");
           }
       })

       res.status(200).json(user);
   })(req, res, next);
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You forgot to import passport config file in your `app.js`.

`import` `passport config` after initializing `passport`.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// Add the line below, which you're missing:
require('./path/to/passport/config/file')(passport);
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to copy that code, but I didn't have the (passport) part. But now I get an  require(...) is not a function error.

Comment: What's `module.exports.init` In your passport config file, shouldn't it be `module.exports = function (passport)`

Comment: Changed to module.exports = function(passport). App wil start now, but I get the same error 'Unknown authentication strategy "local"'

Comment: Haa. working! I moved the code from /strategies/local-strategy.js to auth.config and that was, in combination with the require edit, the trick!

Comment: `TypeError: passport is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

this fix the error. need to use 'local' when you create a new LocalStrategy

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField:'useName',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
```

Answer (score 3):

i have done like this and it worked

> $npm install passport-local

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy; /* this should be after passport*/



 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I export the `passport` object like this:

```
import passport from "passport";
import { LocalStrategy } from "./strategies";

passport.use(LocalStrategy);

export default passport;
```

And then I imported it in the route where I needed:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { login } from "../controllers/auth.controller";
import passport from "../utils/auth";

export const router = Router();

router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }),
  login
);
```

Notice that I imported `passport` from `"../utils/auth"` to use that one that I exported in the first code example.

Answer (score 0):

Add local to your `passport.use`:

```js
passport.use('local', new localStrategy {
  usernameField: "email",
  passwordField: "password"
}
```

And add `require('./config/passport-config/localStrategy')` to the app.js