# Can't make custom named local strategies work in PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

So recently I needed to split my local strategy so it fits our new needs for different types of users logging to our website. Our code up to date looks like:

```
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function(email, password, done) {
   // Verify this email and password, call done with the user
   // if it is correct email and password
   // otherwise, call done with false

});
passport.use(localLogin);
```

And then in our users file we call authenticate like so:

```
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});

router.post('/signin', requireSignin, (request, response, next) => {
    // User already had their email and password Auth'd
    // Give him a token

});
```

We've just changed a few things to leave it like so:

```
passport.use('local.one', localLogin);
```

And then call it as follows:

```
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local.one', {session: false});
```

Tried everything we read in different answers but we can't get it to work. Seems so close yet so far... please help.

P.D.: We've also tried to get a response like:

```
passport.authenticate('local.one', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log('HERE')
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return next(null, false);
    next(null, user);
})
```

But we don't get any data from that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of testing and digging a few conclusions just in case someone finds this same stone on their way:

- LOGS! wow that was helpful...
- After initialize passport on the express() object call this line to load custom config file:

  require('./yourpathtoconfigfileHERE/yourconfigfile')(passport);

Also here is a link that pointed me in the right way:
[Passport: Unknown authentication strategy "local"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585947/passport-unknown-authentication-strategy-local)