# POST http://localhost:5000/login 500 (Internal Server Error)(This is a post request for a login page)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Getting a 500 error for login request: POST http://localhost:5000/login 500 (Internal Server Error). Writing a login page. Not sure where this error is coming from. This is my app.js, routes and form handle submit pages. Can post more code if needed. Using passport to authenticate but dont think the error is coming from there.

```
import express from 'express';


const router = express.Router();


router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) res.send("No User Exists");
      else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.send("Successfully Authenticated");
          console.log(req.user);
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });

export default router;



import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';


import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.js'
import loginRoutes from './routes/login.js'

const app = express();
dotenv.config();


app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/auth', userRoutes);
app.use('/login', loginRoutes);



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)



const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = {
          username: username,
          password: password,

        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login',  user )
          .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          })
      }
```

Comment: Can you share the error message from the server?

Comment: Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"
    at attempt

Comment: There you go. You have to configure the `local` strategy before using it in a route. Check the [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure) on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to initialize Passport in your app.js.
I guess you are using "Passport" for your authentication/authorization goals.
Double-check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585947/passport-unknown-authentication-strategy-local) article if you want any help:

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = await client.post("/sign-in", {email, password});
```

Try this code in handle-submit.